# Amplify Auth : Unable to add User to the Pool

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

I am trying to use [Amplify Auth](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin/q/platform/android#register-a-user) to add users to Cognito User Pool.
I wrote this simple code, but even it doesn't work:

```java
try {
    Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSCognitoAuthPlugin());
} catch (AmplifyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Amplify.Auth.signUp(
    "dragon",
    "Password123@",
    AuthSignUpOptions.builder()
        .userAttribute(AuthUserAttributeKey.email(), "myemailaddress@gmail.com")
        .build(),
    result -> Log.i("AuthQuickStart", "Result: " + result.toString()),
    error -> Log.e("AuthQuickStart", "Sign up failed", error)
);
```

It prints this error to logcat:

```
E/AuthQuickStart: Sign up failed
    AmplifyException {message=Sign up failed, cause=java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool.signUp(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserAttributes, java.util.Map, com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.SignUpHandler)' on a null object reference, recoverySuggestion=See attached exception for more details}
        at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthPlugin$2.onError(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.java:1)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.call(InternalCallback.java:77)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.access$000(InternalCallback.java:34)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:103)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool.signUp(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserAttributes, java.util.Map, com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.SignUpHandler)' on a null object reference
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$13.run(AWSMobileClient.java:1894)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must call `Amplify.configure()` exactly once. It should be called after adding plugins, and before executing any other Amplify command.

It's also true that the Amplify framework should probably return an error message that says that, instead of what it's doing right now. That's a bug with the framework's error reporting.